# What is the Google Chrome Keyboard Shortcut to Open the Current Tab in a New Window?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

According to https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB, the keyboard shortcut to open a tab in a new window is:

> Drag a tab out of the tab strip.

which doesn't seem like a keyboard shortcut at all to me.

Is there really a shortcut for this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think there is a native way of doing that in Chrome.

However there is an Chrome extension specifically for that – [Tab to Window Keyboard Shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-window-keyboard-sh/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh).

Comment: There seems to be no built-in solution so I'll take this as the best answer, as it does the right thing with one keypress.  Thanks @konpyuta.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, there doesn't seem to be a shortcut for popping the current tab out to a new window. But you can try clicking on the address bar then hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or shift-click a link.

The former **duplicates** the current tab in a new window. The latter opens the selected link in a new window. (*Validated on Mac OSX 10.10.*)

Comment: This is good. Though, I will add that you can do `Ctrl+L` to select the address bar then `Shift+Enter` to open duplicate in new window.

Answer (score 2):

Also **Vimium** supports `Shift`+ `w` key binding which does `Move tab to new window`

> more Vimium Keymaps at: https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Keymap

- Chrome Version: Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS Version: Windows 10 21H1
- Vimium Version: 1.67

Answer (score 1):

1. Close current tab <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
2. Open new window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
3. Re-open recently closed tab <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work for me, the new window opens but when you restore the closed tab, it re-opens in the original window instead of the new one.

Comment: When you open new window, is it in focus?  I'll be back at my desk in a few hours so can test then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a single command for that. You might try using something like AutoHotKey to automate the several individual commands involved in copying the url (alt+d, ctrl+c), closing the original tab (ctrl+w), opening the new window (ctrl+n) and then pasting the url (ctrl+v).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the keyboard shortcuts on a Mac:

1. Select the URL of the current page <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Copy the URL <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Close the current tab <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
4. Open a new Chrome browser window <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
5. Paste the copied URL <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
6. Go to the pasted URL <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Saxdaddy's](https://superuser.com/a/906856/1820860) post you can do this in two steps.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - focus address bar

<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Enter</kbd> - open address in new tab

This should work for most use cases except very stringent applications. Though it does not close the original tab.